# Pricing of a non-standard swap contract

Tags: pricing, interest-rate-swap

Here I have a swap product, where a fixed and floating interest rate will be applied on notional amount. Fixed and floating legs involves 2 currencies, one of them is delivery currency (e.g. USD) and other currency is non-delivery currency (e.g. EUR) and pay that non-delivery currency (CCY-2) and receive also in non-delivery currency (CCY-2). Net cashflows will be settled in delivery currency (CCY-1). Payment frequency is quarterly.

In above arrangement, I was told that NPV for fixed leg is defined with following expression

$N \times \sum_{t=1}^{n} 0.25 \times K \times \frac{{FX}_{t=0}}{{FX}_{t}} DF \left(0 , t \right)$

Where $K$ is the fixed rate

$N$ is notional in CCY-2

$DF \left(0 , t \right)$ discount factor in delivery currency with tenor $t$

${FX}_{t}$ is Forward FX rate for CCY-1 / CCY-2

${FX}_{t=0}$ is spot FX rate

With this I am wondering in above expression to calculate the NPV of fixed leg is correct? I mainly have 2 fundamental question

1. Why Discount factor need to be considered in Delivery currency
2. What is the relevance of the expression $\frac{{FX}_{t=0}}{{FX}_{t}}$

Could you please help explaining the accuracy of above expression? If not then what would be the right expression?

Comment: Swap legs, even fixed-coupon, are usually discounted. You say your is non-standard, so perhaps, but usually non-delivery xccy swaps have daycounted legs, i.e. not exactly "0.25", but rather the period fracton.

Comment: @DimitriVulis Thanks for your comment. The number `0.25` as accrual period is just for example, one can replace it by something else. However, I am more focused on the questions in my original post

Comment: Sound like a standard non deliverable IRS (NDIRS / NDS)? If so, I don't think this is common for EUR/USD though but mainly used in emerging markets where the currency is illiquid or subject to exchange restrictions. In case you have Bloomberg, you can load SWPM and use the template for NDIRS where you can select the delivery currency.  Personally, I do not have any exposure to these but I am sure you should find details about pricing online. Intuitively it makes sense, because F/S adjusts for the change in the exchange rate in this period (hedged).

Comment: @AKdemy Thanks for your insight. Could you please elaborate further on your statement `Intuitively it makes sense, because F/S adjusts for the change in the exchange rate in this period (hedged)`? I googled but closest match I get is https://www.lch.com/sites/default/files/media/files/Non-Deliverable%20Interest%20Rate%20Swaps.pdf - which does not detail on pricing though. Any reference/book on pricing such product will be very helpful